# AWS EB single docker getting 404 error - Already Exposed 8000 port

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have created single Docker Python application. Tested it using the local Docker run and it works fine. I

I have exposed the Port 8000 and also included the Dockerrun.aws.json file and only used this file as the image is already uploaded to Docker Hub

```
{
  "AWSEBDockerrunVersion": "1",
  "Image": {
    "Name": "njdocker2014/snakeeyes:2",
    "Update": "true"
  },
  "Ports": [
    {
      "ContainerPort": 8000,
      "HostPort": 8000
    }
  ],
  "Logging": "/var/log/snakeyes",
  "Command": "gunicorn -b 0.0.0.0:8000 --access-logfile - 'snakeeyes.app:create_app()'"
}
```

Dockerfile as EXPOSE 8000

And The Docker is running in the EC2 Container as shown below,

```
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-47-66 ~]$ docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
dd757b4a0102        8af7a8cee988        "gunicorn -b 0.0.0.0…"   8 minutes ago       Up 8 minutes        8000/tcp            condescending_pare
```

When I access the EB DNS URL, it gives 404 not Found, And Even the Docker Logs also show same Error,

```
[2019-03-25 06:47:01 +0000] [10] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 10
172.17.0.1 - - [25/Mar/2019:06:53:17 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 232 "-" "-"
```

What else to be done to send the request to port 8000 inside the container.

Comment: Since the docker logs printed 404, it means that your port mapping worked fine. It could be the application issue where it couldn't map the incoming URL to a controller properly.

Comment: The same App works outside simply if I run with publishing the ports
docker run -p 8000:8000 -d snakeyes

Now http://localhost:8000 works. But When it goes through EB it wont work.

I even tried other Flask Apps, it works, but this Flask App is a Gunicron based. But I believe what you run inside the docker should not be the problem as long, it is able to get the request.

What I am not understanding is that, why my Docker Python App is not accepting the connection

Comment: I have deployed many other apps with and without Docker in the AWS EB, and it has worked fine. But this is gunicron based Python flask app using the Single Docker Container.
Very simple app with few routes and using few blueprints. But does not work when deployed through AWS EB.